# How to make a call to Rest-Endpoint which are deployed on Linux machine as a Docker Container

Tags: node.js, linux, curl, docker, nodes

Apologies if Duplicate:
I Have a docker container which is a Node.js service. I want to test the endpoint of that service from the same linux machine.I am testing the endpoint using `curl` command I get `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PORT

RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs npm nodejs-legacy vim

RUN mkdir /database_service
ADD . /database_service
WORKDIR /database_service

RUN npm install -g express
RUN npm install -g path
RUN npm cache clean


EXPOSE $PORT

ENTRYPOINT [ "node",  "server.js" ]
CMD [ $PORT, $ENVIRONMENT ]
```

Here is My configuration file:

```
module.exports = {
        database: {
            username: 'someusername',
            password: 'somepassword',
            host: '13.68.86.237',
            port: 27017,
            name: 'admin'   
        },
        "sandbox_config": {
            "commerce.api.endpoint":"sandbox_ep",
            "eurekaInstance":{
                    "instanceId":'10.71.9.40:database-service:'+process.env.PORT || 9200,
                    "hostName": 'database-service',
                    "app": 'database-service',
                    "ipAddr": '10.71.9.40',
                    "port": { '$': process.env.PORT || 9200, '@enabled': 'true' },
                    "securePort": { '$': 443, '@enabled': 'false' },
                    "dataCenterInfo": {
                        '@class': 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo',
                         "name": 'MyOwn'
                    },
                    "homePageUrl": 'http://database-service:'+process.env.PORT || 9200+'/',
                    "statusPageUrl": 'http://database-service:'+process.env.PORT || 9200+'/info',
                    "healthCheckUrl": 'http://database-service:'+process.env.PORT || 9200+'/health',
                    "vipAddress": 'database-service',
                    "secureVipAddress": 'database-service',
                    "isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer": 'false',
                    "leaseInfo": { 
                        "renewalIntervalInSecs": 60000,
                        "durationInSecs": 60000,
                    }
            },
            "eurekaConfig":{
                 "host":'eureka-server',
                 "port":8761,
                 "servicePath":'/eureka/apps/'
             }
        }

};
```

Please suggest is there something missing here or wrong command.

[Here is the Snap for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJH03.png)

Comment: We'd need to see your web-server configuration and Dockerfile

Comment: @Rawkode : I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run a `docker image inspect image_tag` you'll see that the variables you believe are being interpolated in your `CMD` instruction won't be resolved until container run-time.

Add this after your `ARG` instructions

```
ENV PORT $PORT
ENV ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT
```

To ensure the default environment variables are available at run-time

Comment: `[
    {
        "Id": "02d56107ceb0a229387178c422c3aa6369dd53ee2687c90610cda15f15286141",
        "Created": "2017-05-03T07:40:14.730079112Z",
        "Path": "node",
        "Args": [
            "server.js",
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "[ $PORT, $ENVIRONMENT ]"
        ],
` Those things are allredy in place

Comment: Yes, `$PORT` is there, not the expanded value from your build. So you need to add the `ENV` lines I suggested, or pass `-e PORT=80` in your `docker run` command.

Comment: This is the result of `docker ps` `02d56107ceb0        jcibts_swm_sb/database_service:v0.1           "node server.js /b..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:9003->9003/tcp   database_service`

Comment: I am passing it with the run command. Please see the image that I have attached with my question for `docker ps`

Comment: `docker run -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --network "sandbox_cloud" --name ${SERVICE_NAME} -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}` this is a command I have written in shell file and calling the shell file by passing param

Comment: Port number is propagating properly. please see my image which I attach for docker ps result

Comment: No, port number is not propegating properly. It's exposed, sure. But your web server isn't running on that port because you never provide a $PORT environment variable at runtime. Add `-e PORT=80` to your docker run command to verify

Comment: Understood, I ll try to fix that. Thanks for the reply and help.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks my problem is fixed.

Comment: Nice one! That's great